# I want to create an event which will Fire when someone clicks on the IFrame launcher on the bottom right of my page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to create a trigger which will fire when someone clicks on the IFrame launcher present in the bottom right of the page. That launcher doesnt take to another website, it will just open a container and ask for the SignUp thing. I dont wanna do with cross-domain tracking. Just that a tag should be fired when someone clicks on that launcher. Is it possible?

Comment: Look into event listeners

Comment: Look into addEventListener()

Answer (score 0):

**using jquery**

```
$("#id").click(function() {
    // do something here
});
```